# how to make a jump script 2d unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a jump script in unity 2d but nothing has worked so I was hoping someone could give me a working jump script?

I've tried all over the web but nothing has worked

Comment: Instead of asking for someone to give you code you should show what you have attempted and explain how it is not working

Comment: the problem is I am completely new so I didn't know how to do any of it :)

Answer (score 1):

To make a jump script, you need two things:
A force or transform to make your sprite move up and a check to make sure your sprite can't jump forever.

[Here is a useful video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6Q6VHueWnU)

Here is some example code:

```
// In your movement class
public float jumpHeight = 5f; // A public float so we can change its value easily in the inspector
public static bool isJumping = false; // This bool will tell us if our character is jumping or not
```

---

```
// Inside the Update method:
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && (isJumping == false)) 
{
   gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpHeight), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

---

```
// Methods, inside your movement class
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
    {
       isJumping = false;
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
    {
        isJumping = true;
    }
}
```

There are many ways to create a jumping script - this is just a simple one.

In the future, like UnholySheep said, provide some code of what you have tried already - then others can help you out and explain where you went wrong so it doesn't happen again.

Good luck coding!

Comment: thank you so much ill test it when I get a chance @Wzrd